# Как убрать текст ссылки-картинки?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, requests, url, response

Есть запрос по методу. Скрипт запрашивает текст и картинку. Далее создаю список all_info. Добавляю в него весь запрос ->

```
for post in data:
   text = post['text']+'\n'
   all_info.append(text)
   all_info.append("\n")
   try:
       if post['attachments'][0]['type'] not in all_info:
           all_info.append(post['attachments'][-1]['photo']['sizes'][-1]['url'])
       else:
           print('pass')
   except KeyError:
       print('Нет фото')
```

После, всё это летит в телеграмм бота и там выходит по нажатию на определённую кнопку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, что бы текст ссылки не показывался в сообщении, не мешая выводу картинки в сообщении?

В файле bot.py функция вывода сообщения такая.
Просто выводит весь запрос в сообщение

```
def parse(update, context):
   response = requests.get('https://9630-145-255-9-3.ap.ngrok.io')
   update.message.reply_text(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно вырезать url адрес картинки и отправить reply_photo

```
import re

def parse(update, context):
    response = requests.get("https://9630-145-255-9-3.ap.ngrok.io")

    discription = response.text
    link_img = re.search(r"https.*", discription).group(0)

    update.message.reply_photo(
        photo=link_img, caption=discription.replace(link_img, "")
    )
```

Comment: О! Спасибо! 
Я всё думал как это можно так же вырезать через Filters.regex
Но никак не получалось.